# create a custom external class in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create an external class in Laravel, I want to use this class in my cotroller function.

What is the best way to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Create a class and define its namespace. For example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;
class MyClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        dd('It\'s working');
    }
}
```

Run `composer du` command.

You'll be able to use the class in a controller with:

```
(new App\Services\MyClass)->doSomething();
```

Or with [IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container):

```
app('App\Services\MyClass')->doSomething();
```

If you're using IoC, you'll also be able to inject the class into controller constructor:

```
use App\Services\MyClass;
protected $myClass;
public function __construct(MyClass $myclass)
{
    $this->myClass = $myClass;
}
public function index()
{
    $this->myClass->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, what does `composer du` do?

Comment: @AndyHolmes `composer du` is the same as `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @AndyHolmes as Vindur said, it's one of the shortcuts for [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)

Answer (score 0):

Used common function any file like controller,models and all blade file valid.

Please try your helpers.php file inner created.

file path like : laravel/app/helpers.php

Code

```
if (!function_exists('classActivePath')) {

   function classActivePath($path) {
       return Request::is($path) ? ' class="active"' : '';
   }

}
```